# VB.NET - The handle is invalid

Tags: vb.net, printing, printdocument

Good day, 
I am trying to print a document using PrintDocument

```
Using doc As New Printing.PrintDocument
      With doc
           .PrinterSettings = dlg.PrinterSettings
           AddHandler doc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintToPage
           If .PrinterSettings.IsValid Then
              doc.Print()
           End If
       End With
End Using
```

And after the ".Print()" it throws an error of "The handle is invalid".

```
System.Drawing
    at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnStartPage(PrintDocument document, PrintPageEventArgs e) 
    at System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog.OnStartPage(PrintDocument document, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.PrintLoop(PrintDocument document)
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
```

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application?  If so, try adding the `PrintDocument` to your form in the designer instead of creating it and destroying it in code.

Comment: I tried adding it in the designer but it still throw the same error..

Comment: I tried printing it with Microsoft XPS Document Writer and it works properly, But If i tried printing it through PDF and printer, it throws the error "The handle is invalid"